# if(isset($_POST['submit'])) twice not working second time

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am pulling my hair out. I had this working earlier.

My `confirm.php` checks variables from the previous page's form. Then echos them so the viewer can confirm the answers. If everything looks good they can click the paypal image `name="submit"` and it goes through the isset again and sends `mail()` and updates the URL for the form action then post variables to paypal with some javascript code I got help with earlier.

**EDIT:**
I upload more streamline code:

form.php page:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="send"/>
</form>
```

Confirm.php:

```
<?
ini_set("display_errors","2");
ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL);

$url = '';
    if (isset($_POST['send']))
        {
            $data = $_POST['name'];
        }else{ 
            echo "SEND is not Set";
        }


    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $data = $_POST['data'];
            $my_message = ' TEST DATA:<br/><br/>Child Name'. $data .'';
            $subject = 'Mike TEST';
            $headers = "From: mrawers@xxxx.com\r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: mrawers@xxxx.com\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

            $url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

            mail("mike.rawers@xxxx.com",$my_message,$subject,$headers);
        }else{ 
            echo "SUBMIT is not Set";
        }
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<form action="<? echo $url; ?>" method="post">
    Name:   <? echo $data; ?><input type="hidden" name="data" value="<? echo $data; ?>"/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?
if ($url != "") {
?>
<script language="javascript">
document.forms[0].submit();
</script>
<?
}else{ echo "URL NOT SET";}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see submit buttons in this form..If it's in another page, that works for that page and not this one...

Comment: doesnt <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="Submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
 work as a submit button?

Comment: I fixed you formatting and as you can clearly see there is an extra `{` after `mail()`

Comment: LOL I must be still sleepy i didn't see that :D And maybe I dind't even understood the Q, where's the "twice"part? I see a form that,if submitted,checks if isset confirm (which is,since it's hidden and value is provided) and so does it's routine. Have you tried checking if it is actually set the submit? (if...else echo 'not set').

Comment: infact there are quite a few unmatched braces. Can you confirm these are not the issue and update to code above accordingly.

Comment: I will edit and update with all the code. I tried stripping the extra out. sorry. thanks for you help.

Comment: The script gets the data from the previous page and echos it to so the viewer can confirm. The url for the action is blank. when the user clicks the paypal button the page reloads but this time since confirm is set the form's action url is update (for the same form) and then at the bottom a javascript auto submits the page again only this time it goes to paypal. I know its not very clear just let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Just to rule out that the problem isn't the image-submit button, chang it to a regular input type="submit" name="submit" and see if it works. And add an `else` clause to the `if(isset($_POST['submit'])` just to be clear (maybe var_dump the $_POST array there, so you see if everything is set correctly)

Comment: I put the else after the isset and it went into there so its not getting reading the submit from the image. When I use a submit button it goes in but the javascript doesnt submit it again. lol so it just sits there instead of going to paypal.

Comment: `form action="test.php`? Wait, can you post the code inside `test.php`?

Comment: form action="test.php should be confirm.php I had the name changed so it made more sense. sorry.

Comment: http://www.2020mediaonline.com/stackoverflow/testreg.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your form submit it set variables in `$_POST` as

```
$_POST['Submit_x']  $_POST['Submit_y']
```

That's why your condition fails every time.

You are checking with the `$_POST['submit']` PHP is the case sensitive in respect of variable names.

Comment: OK is there a way around this? I didnt know it did that.

Answer (score 1):

```
value="<? echo $data; ?>"?
```

This is bad practice. if `$data` contains a double-quote, it'll break your form. As is, blindly outputting user-provided data is exactly how XSS attacks occur. You should have, at bare minimum:

```
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($data) ?>">
```

which'll keep your form intact.

Answer (score -1):

Your submit tag is written with a capital 'S':

```
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="Submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
```

but your PHP is checking for a lowercase 'submit'.
On an additional note, I would add a hidden field with the name submit, older IEs don't submit the value of a submit button (at least not `input type="submit"` don't know about `input type="image"` though)

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
```

in your PHP check for

```
 if (intval($_POST['submitted']) > 0)
```

Comment: I missed typed that for the post. Sorry it is lowercase in my script. I add echos at the top of the page and get nothing.

Comment: && @Denoteone NEVER call anything in a form for name="submit" if you ever want to submit the form using javascript submit()