# Submit data twice on one page

Tags: php, javascript, html, double-submit-problem

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269656/ifisset-postsubmit-twice-not-working-second-time) but had so much crap code that I have broken it down to the minimum ammount of code this time. Form page sends data to confirm page.

Confirm page echos data to user so they can double check it. then if they click "submit" it reloads the same page sends an email to me then it updates the url for the forms action and a little javascript submits the form again without the user knowing it since $url is not empty. Everything is working but the **javascript is not doing its part.** the page just sits there and I can see the javascript in the page source so its there.

Form page:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="send"/>
</form>
```

confirm page:

```
<?
ini_set("display_errors","2");
ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL);

$url = '';
    if (isset($_POST['send']))
        {
            $data = $_POST['name'];
        }else{ 
            echo "SEND is not Set";
        }


    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $data = $_POST['data'];
            $my_message = ' TEST DATA:<br/><br/>Child Name'. $data .'';
            $subject = 'Mike TEST';
            $headers = "From: mrawers@xxxx.com\r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: mrawers@xxxx.com\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

            $url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

            mail("mike.rawers@xxxx.com",$my_message,$subject,$headers);
        }else{ 
            echo "SUBMIT is not Set";
        }
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<form action="<? echo $url; ?>" method="post">
    Name:   <? echo $data; ?><input type="hidden" name="data" value="<? echo $data; ?>"/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?
if ($url != "") {
?>
<script language="javascript">
document.forms[0].submit();
</script>
<?
}else{ echo "URL NOT SET";}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can edit your original question.

Comment: where is the JavaScript code?

Comment: sorry still new to the site... I wasnt sure if it would not make sense since most of the comments and feedback on the old questions were about how junky the code was.

Comment: @gunnar at the bottom fo the page under the form. <?
if ($url != "") {
?>
<script language="javascript">
document.forms[0].submit();
</script>
<?
}else{ echo "URL NOT SET";}
?>

Comment: do you have this on a testing environment or something? obviously without the mail() calls, but at least a barebones non working system

Comment: http://www.2020mediaonline.com/stackoverflow/testreg.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this line of code than you'll get what you want:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
```

WHY?

That's because of the "name".
The input element with the name "submit" is conflict with the submit function.
You wanted to call the "submit" function, but the broswer just got the "submit" element.

You can take a try of this:

```
alert(document.forms[0].submit);
```

It's a element.

Btw, You can excute the "submit" function without the "submit" element.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than re-posting the data to another URL why not use a cURL object in the PHP to send it after emailing?

Comment: I can do that.... but now I just want to understand WHY its not working when it looks like it should.

Comment: If I use curl i know I can send the post data to the url but can I redirect the user there as well?

Comment: Hmm no it won't, I suppose you could do a 301 redirect to repost but I suspect that's just about as much of a hack as your solution or worse it might not work reliably depend on the browser.