# CakePHP Submit image type differentiate for Save and Print & Save

Tags: image, cakephp, form-submit

In my CakePHP 1.3 version, I have two submit type image tags as mentioned below:

```
echo $form->submit('save-print.jpg' , array('name'=>'savenprint','value'=>"savenprint",'id'=>"savenprint"));

echo $form->submit('save.jpg');
```

Now, What I want is to identify in my Controller, that which button is submitted, whether "Save" or "Print & Save"

So I have applied `name and value` to each of them and in Chrome browser, i am getting name and value pair, while in Mozilla Firefox, I do not get the same.

Any idea, how that can be achieved? or what is wrong or missing in my code.

Earliest response will be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: How do you access the values in your controller? For me `$this->Form->submit('Send it!', array('name'=>'send_test'))` and checking in the controller like this `if (isset($this->params['form']['send_test'])) { ...` works fine in Firefox.

Comment: @pixelistik: it doesn't work with image type, returns something like this for ex. `[sbmtfrm_x] => 21 [sbmtfrm_y] => 15`

Comment: Could you show the full form code from the view, and the corresponding controller code, too? And the output of `debug($this->params['form'])` in your controller action.

Comment: Hope this link will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269656/ifisset-postsubmit-twice-not-working-second-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Form should looks like:

```
echo $form->submit('save-print.jpg' , array('name'=>'savenprint','value'=>"save",'id'=>"savenprint"));
echo $form->submit('save.jpg', array('name'=>'savenprint','value'=>"savenprint",'id'=>"savenprint"));
```

In your Controller use:

```
if($this->data['ModelName']['sbmtfrm_x'] == 'save')
{
     //Your save code here
}
else if($this->data['ModelName']['sbmtfrm_x'] == 'savenprint')
{
     //Your savenprint code here
}
```

One another solution is to make a hidden field and set the value of it onclick of submit button in your jquery code like in the following way:

Your form:

```
echo $form->submit('save-print.jpg' , array('name'=>'savenprint','value'=>"save",'id'=>"savenprint", 'class' => 'submitBtn'));    
echo $form->submit('save.jpg', array('name'=>'savenprint','value'=>"savenprint",'id'=>"savenprint", 'class' => 'submitBtn'));
echo $form->hidden('sbmtValue', array('id' => 'sbmtValue', 'value' => ''));
```

And your jquery code should looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.submitBtn').click(function(){
       $('#sbmtValue').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

And in your controller's action use:

```
if($this->data['ModelName']['sbmtValue'] == 'save')
{
     //Your save code here
}
else if($this->data['ModelName']['sbmtValue'] == 'savenprint')
{
     //Your savenprint code here
}
```

Hope it will work for you.